# Append words and delete the lines based on pattern in awk

Tags: unix, awk, sed, gawk

If the file having lines where first three strings are same, I want to append information present in the other lines in 4th and 5th strings to the first line in the 4th string and delete those lines.

For Example I have lines like

```
<a.com> <b.com> <c.com> <site> <domain> <lang>
<a.com> <b.com> <c.com> <site2> <domain2> <lang>
<a.com> <b.com> <c.com> <site3> <domain2> <lang>
```

Output should be like

```
<a.com> <b.com> <c.com> <site,site2,site3,domain2> <domain> <lang>
```

I tried in sed and awk but was not successful. I am successful in appending the information but could nt delete the lines

Thanks
Pallavi

Comment: Show your successful code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 'N;N;G;h
s/\(\(<[^>]\{1,\}> *\)\{3\}\)<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>\(.*\)\(\n\)\1 *<\([^>]\{1,\}\)> *\(\(<[^>]\{1,\}> *\)\{2\}\) *\5/\1<\3,\6>\4\5/
t void
:void
s/\(\(<[^>]\{1,\}> *\)\{3\}\)<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>\(.*\)\(\n\)\1 *<\([^>]\{1,\}\)> *\(\(<[^>]\{1,\}> *\)\{2\}\) *\5/\1<\3,\6>\4\5/
t ok
x;b
:ok
s/.$//' YourFile
```

Work for your file based on this 3 line but not easy to read nor understand due to lot of group reference.